# NSInvalidArgumentException Application threw exception NSInvalidArgumentException: data parameter is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I received an error that says "NSInvalidArgumentException
Application threw exception NSInvalidArgumentException: data parameter is nil" and I really have no idea my codes is causing this error.

```
-(void)AddressAfterDelay{
    if ([[[self withStringAddress:[self._dictSearchResults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Address",self._strFieldName]]] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {

    MapAddressViewController *mapAddressViewController = [[[MapAddressViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil withAddress:[[[[self withStringAddress:[self._dictSearchResults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Address",self._strFieldName]]] objectForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"formatted_address"] objectAtIndex:0] withAccountInformation:self._dictAccountInformation withTitleAddress:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Address",self._strFieldName]] autorelease];
    [mapAddressViewController setDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapAddressViewController animated:YES];

    } else {
        [self._fieldValidation alertMessage:@"Import Genius" Message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location of this address cannot be determined. %@",[self._dictSearchResults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Address",self._strFieldName]]]];
    }
    [self stopIndicator];
}

-(NSDictionary*)withStringAddress:(NSString*)Address{
    Address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]];
    Address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"+"]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false",Address]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if(!error)
    {
        //log response
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint, but chances are `dataWithContentsOfURL` returned `nil`; you should check before attempting to decode the json

Comment: @Paulw11 that is noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case,

to solve it by

Add -all_load to the other linker flags in your build settings.

> -all_load forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees, even those without Objective-C code.

---

more desp:

> The "selector not recognized" runtime exception occurs due to an issue between the implementation of standard UNIX static libraries, the linker and the dynamic nature of Objective-C. Objective-C does not define linker symbols for each function (or method, in Objective-C) - instead, linker symbols are only generated for each class. If you extend a pre-existing class with categories, the linker does not know to associate the object code of the core class implementation and the category implementation. This prevents objects created in the resulting application from responding to a selector that is defined in the category.

> To resolve this issue, the target linking against the static library must pass the -ObjC option to the linker. This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on existing classes. Follow these steps to pass -ObjC to the linker:

> In Xcode, double-click the target's name under "Targets" in the Project window.Choose the Build pane from the ensuing Info window.Scroll down to the Other Linker Flags build setting under the Linking collection and set its value to -ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

I see you response data in `withStringAddress` method. I think you should waiting response from url first in another thread and call method navigation to `MapAddressViewController` in main thread after data responsed.